# Is there a way to select and aggregate in the same laravel query?

Tags: sql, laravel-5.6

I'd like to create a query of this equivalence

```
select classroom.*, count(students.id) as headcount 
from classroom
     left join students on classroom.id = students.classroom_id
where classroom.id = 1
```

But after some experimenting, I'm getting the idea that I cannot mix a "select" and a "count" in the same query. I must be wrong... but I can't figure it out. I don;t see how to do it using Eloquent ORM either.

Something like this:

```
 $classroomDescription= DB::table('classroom')
    ->leftjoin('students ', 'classroom.id', '=', 'students .id')
    ->select('classroom.*')
    ->count('students.id as headcount')
    ->where('classroom.id','=', $id)
    ->toSql();
    //->get();
```

Unless I was to run two seperate queries and merge the results ... but that just sounds inefficient.

Comment: You cannot do `select classroom.*, count(classroom.id) as headcount`. A `group by` has to be used if you use any aggregate function. `select classroom.id, count(*) from classroom left join students on students.classroom_id = classroom.id where classroom.id = 'x' group by classroom.id`. This is not the answer, but wanted to show you that you have to use a group by if you use any aggregate function.

Comment: Cheers, & thanks - my SQL knowledge is non-existant at this time :)